# Can multiple servers listen on the same port when no Bind/Accept has occured

Tags: tcp, port, connections

When you have a Windows machine (server or home edition) which is running 2 servers, and they are both listening on port 4000, however none have had a request to connect?

What happens when a client attempts to connect?

Or is 2 things listening on the same port on the same machine not even a possible scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible, at least in normal circumstances. Not sure if there might be dark magic tricks to make it possible somehow, but I don't see why anyone would want to do this.

Comment: I don't want to do it, I'm just verifying of the possibility of it ever occuring.

Comment: It's not possible; even with black magic. It's possible the two programs talk to each other and negotiate something, but this is highly unlikely. The first one to start will almost certainly grab the port and no let go.